# Android CPU awake and Battery Depletion due to Background Service

Tags: android, service, android-volley, android-sensors, battery

I am working on an Sensors App that needs to measure *acceleration* and *position* every second. These measurements take place in a background **Service**.
For the acceleration I use the **Accelerometer Sensor** and for the location the **FusedLocationApi** of Google Play Services.

But as shown in the screenshots below, **the CPU is always awake (why?)** and the battery is depleted very quickly when the app is running. I closed the app and the Service kept running (which is what I want) during the night, and when I woke up, my battery was completely drained. Given that the wifi was turned off, the battery depletion couldn't be caused by the http connection.

So, is the accelerometer the cause?
**What can be done to reduce power consumption in such a case?**

Screenshots:
[Battery History details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uClSe.png)
[Battery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9TNs.png)

```java
public class MyService extends Service implements 
    SensorEventListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        if ((accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)) != null) {
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
            .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;

        if ((sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) && accelerometer != null) {
            double accelX = event.values[0];
            double accelY = event.values[1];
            double accelZ = event.values[2];
        }

    }

}
```

The UI is updated periodically every second. I use a **Handler** that runs a **Runnable**:

```java
private Runnable serviceRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (activity != null) {
                activity.updateSensorDataToClient(mSensorData);
            }

            mHandler.postDelayed(serviceRunnable, 1000);
        }
}
```

Another **Runnable** sends data every 10 seconds to an external Database. For this communication I use the **Volley** library.

```java
private Runnable networkRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        networkConnection.sendDataToServer(processedData);

        mHandler.postDelayed(networkRunnable, 10*1000);
    }
}
```

The `networkConnection` is a `Class` and has a method `sendDataToServer` that stores the current sensor data in local a SQLite Database. If there is a connection, the local data are sent to the external DB.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, the accelerometer is lightweight in terms of battery use. GPS is more of a concern and should be used sparingly.

The much bigger problem is the frequency with which you are reading out your sensors. By polling every second, the device never gets a chance to go to sleep. You already noticed this as you were saying that the CPU kept running. And that's of course because you've instructed your Handler to run code every second. I imagine you must have your reasons for wanting sensor data every second, but the better approach is to respond to changes rather than to actively poll for data.

The `FusedLocationApi` offers ways to let you run code on the condition that some user activity or movement has been detected. Android can then run your code only when it matters, and go to sleep if there are no significant changes in the sensor data.

For more general tips about preventing battery drain please check out some of the recent battery performance videos by Colt McAnlis. This one for instance:
https://youtu.be/4D7_N2XEw20

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I tried your suggestion and I used the `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates`. It tuned out however that the main cause for my battery depletion was that I was recording from the microphone all the time.